# DDEV fails writing TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL on Drupal9+ on mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, docker, ddev

I am facing an issue where "SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED" set in the database get overwritten in DDEV to REPEATABLE-READ either on restart or restore.

It's a multi site and all sites work fine but do get below on a snapshot restore:

```
>  ddev snapshot restore
multi_20230518092603
Stopping db container for snapshot restore of 'multi_20230518092603-mysql_5.7.gz'...
With large snapshots this may take a long time.
This will normally time out after 120 seconds (max of all container timeouts)
but you can increase it by changing default_container_timeout.
Using custom PHP configuration: [/home/user/project/multi/.ddev/php/apc-php.ini]
Custom configuration is updated on restart.
If you don't see your custom configuration taking effect, run 'ddev restart'.
Container ddev-multi-dba  Running
Container ddev-multi-web  Running
Container ddev-multi-db  Started
Container ddev-router  Running
Not creating CMS settings files because disable_settings_management=true
unable to SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED: stdout='', stderr='', err=ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-multi docker-compose -f /home/user/project/multi/.ddev/.ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml exec -T db bash -c set -eu && ( mysql -e "SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;" 2>/dev/null)', action='[exec -T db bash -c set -eu && ( mysql -e "SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;" 2>/dev/null)]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr=''
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Task failed: Exec command 'mysql -uroot -proot -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS multi; GRANT ALL ON multi.* to 'db'@'%';"' in container/service 'db': exit status 1
```

As can't quite figure this one out, as database connections seam to work. "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/tmp/mysql.sock'" tmp is set to 777

Any pointers on this are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Thomas - I dont't think your problem has to do with `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`, that's a standard thing that's done to Drupal9+ projects on start. It looks to me like it's that your database server is coming up slowly or something like that. You can easily test this by changing the project type to `php`, `ddev config --project-type=php` and then it won't change the `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`. But like I say, I think something else is probably wrong, and it would be better for you to provide full information about environment (`ddev debug test` output into a gist on gist.github.com

Comment: Or come on over to Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k, or open an issue, but please do give the full information from `ddev debug test` in your issue, and explain what you've done to solve it, and whether it happens with a simple Drupal quickstart, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#drupal

Comment: Hi @Randy, thanks so much for the quick reply. Got some time tomorrow and will hop over to Discord with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there were two bugs here that affected mysql or mysql:5.7. Issue opened in https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/4933; Both bugs appear to be fixed in https://github.com/ddev/ddev/pull/4934 - please take a look. This fix will appear in the DDEV v1.22.0 release, and in prerelease versions prior to that.